# Angularjs IE7 issue

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-7

i have just got a basic app going but i cant get it to work in IE7 
Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="ng-app" ng-app="myapp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org">
<head>
<title></title>
<!-- Load Angular -->
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add HTML 5 Shim -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Add Json support -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="js/json3.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Support these angular tags -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script>
document.createElement('ng-include');
document.createElement('ng-pluralize');
document.createElement('ng-view');

// Optionally these for CSS
document.createElement('ng:include');
document.createElement('ng:pluralize');
document.createElement('ng:view');
</script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<!-- Template Start -->
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<input ng-model="name">
<h1 ng-bind="name">{{name}}</h1>
<h1>{{age - 5}}</h1>
</div>
<!-- Template End -->


<!-- Load my scripts -->
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
angular.bootstrap(document);
});

var Ctrl = function($scope) {
$scope.name = "Lenny";
$scope.age = 31;
};
```

I am using Internet explorer 11 and i am switching it into IE7 more to test how it works. All i get is the curly braces in IE7 but works fine in IE8.

Comment: Have you disabled SCE to support IE7? I found this worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740857/angularjs-and-quirks-mode-blank-screen-on-ie8/21802157#21802157

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS isn't supported in IE7 and even with IE8 it [will have idiosyncrasies](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie).

> The project currently supports and will attempt to fix bugs for IE8 and above. The continuous integration server runs all the tests against IE8. See http://ci.angularjs.org.
>
> IE7 and below are not tested and the project makes no guarantee that Angular will work on it. A subset of the AngularJS functionality may work. It is up to you to test and decide whether it works for your particular app.
>
> It is very unlikely that issues specific to IE7 or earlier will be given any time by the core team. GitHub