# AngularJS and quirks mode: blank screen on IE8+

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I'm working on an Angular project that will be included in a HTML page I don't have control on. 
Actually I only have access to what is inside the `<body>` element.

There are many constraints which are not the easiest to deal with: 
1- I can't change the doctype: 
    
2- I can't remove this meta tag: 
    
3- The app has to load an XML file

I managed to overcome points 1 and 3 but point 2 gives me a headache !
Here is the error I get when I test on IE8+ (it works fine on IE7 and other browsers):

> [$sce:iequirks] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$sce/iequirks
>   IE8 in quirks mode is unsupported
>   error in component $sce
>   Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode.  You can fix this by adding the text  to the top of your HTML document.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce for more information.

I found many solutions on forums but no one has worked so far... 
Especially hoped that disabling $sceProvider (code below) would make the app work on IE8+ but it didn't:

```
angular.module('ie7support', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
// Completely disable SCE to support IE7.
$sceProvider.enabled(false);`
});
```

I even tried to add `<!doctype html>` to the top of my HTML document, which I am not allowed to but which I did just for the test, and it doesn't solve the problem.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated cause I'm really stuck right now...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it !!

I simply needed to give the name of my app instead of silly "ie7support" in the code below:

```
angular.module('ie7support', []).config(function($sceProvider) {
// Completely disable SCE to support IE7.
$sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
```

Found thanks to a deeper look at this article: 
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$sce

Hope it can help some of you !

Comment: Great. Odd having to support IE7 in 2014, but being that a requirement this answer is great, thanks.

Comment: For newbies like me to Angular, can you please mention where do we add this code ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[IE in quirks mode is not supported by AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24sce%3aiequirks)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer Adam but according to these messages, disabling $sce completely helps AngularJS to support IE in quirks mode...

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3633

[[$sce:iequirks] Strict Contextual Escaping does not support Internet Explorer version < 9 in quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506458/sceiequirks-strict-contextual-escaping-does-not-support-internet-explorer-ve)